# Add elements of a list as a new band to images of an Imagecollection

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have an `imageCollection` with 40 images in it, lets say.
And I have a list of numbers, `L=[l1, l2, ..., l40]` , with length 40.

How can I add each entry of the list `L` as a new band to images in my `imageCollection`?

Here is my code

```
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017");


var aoi =  ee.Feature(countries.filterMetadata('country_na', 'equals', 'Kenya')
           .first()).buffer(1000).geometry();

var start_date = '2015-01-01';
var end_date = '2017-01-01';

// Add predictors for SG fitting, using date difference
// We prepare for order 3 fitting, but can be adapted to lower order fitting later on

function prep_savitz(img) {
  var dstamp = ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start'));
  var ddiff = dstamp.difference(ee.Date(start_date), 'hour');
  img = img.select(['NDVI', 'EVI']).divide(32768.0).set('date', dstamp);
  return img.addBands(ee.Image(1).toFloat().rename('constant'))
            .addBands(ee.Image(ddiff).toFloat().rename('t'))
            .addBands(ee.Image(ddiff).pow(ee.Image(2)).toFloat().rename('t2'))
            .addBands(ee.Image(ddiff).pow(ee.Image(3)).toFloat().rename('t3'));
}

var modis_res = modis.filterDate(start_date, end_date).filterBounds(aoi);
modis_res = modis_res.map(prep_savitz);

// Step 2: Set up Savitzky-Golay smoothing

// Define the axes of variation in the collection array.
var imageAxis = 0;
var bandAxis = 1;

// Set polynomial order
var order = 3;
var coeffFlattener = [['constant', 'x', 'x2', 'x3']];
var indepSelectors = ['constant', 't', 't2', 't3'];


var window_size = 9;
var half_window = (window_size - 1)/2;


var array = modis_res.toArray();

// Solve
function getLocalFit(i) {
  // Get a slice corresponding to the window_size of the SG smoother
  var subarray = array.arraySlice(imageAxis, ee.Number(i).int(), ee.Number(i).add(window_size).int());
  var predictors = subarray.arraySlice(bandAxis, 2, 2 + order + 1);
  var response = subarray.arraySlice(bandAxis, 0, 1); // NDVI
  var coeff = predictors.matrixSolve(response);

  coeff = coeff.arrayProject([0]).arrayFlatten(coeffFlattener);
  return coeff;
}

// For the remainder, use modis_res as a list of images
var modis_res_List = modis_res.toList(modis_res.size());
var runLength = ee.List.sequence(0, modis_res_List.size().subtract(window_size));

// Run the SG solver over the series, and return the smoothed image version
var sg_series = runLength.map(function(i) {
  var ref = ee.Image(modis_res_List.get(ee.Number(i).add(half_window)));
  return getLocalFit(i).multiply(ref.select(indepSelectors)).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()).copyProperties(ref);
});

// 3B. Now get a profile for a buffered point. 
// Make sure to place the point in the centre of a homogenous area (reduces noise) 
var pt = ee.Geometry.Point(39.89, -1.8516).buffer(500);

// Build a stack for all images in the collection
function stack(i1, i2){
  return ee.Image(i1).addBands(ee.Image(i2));
}

var s1orig = modis_res_List.slice(1).iterate(stack, modis_res_List.get(0));

var s1sged = sg_series.slice(1).iterate(stack, sg_series.get(0));

// Get samples from both series.
var y = ee.Image(s1orig).select(['NDVI(..)*']).reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), pt, 10).values();
var xlabels = ee.Image(s1orig).select(['t(..)*']).reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), pt, 10).values();
var smoothy = ee.Image(s1sged).select(['sum(..)*']).reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), pt, 10).values();

smoothy = ee.List.repeat(smoothy.get(0), half_window).cat(smoothy).cat(ee.List.repeat(smoothy.get(-1), half_window));
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////
//////////     Combine imageCollection with the list
//////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
smoothy = ee.List(smoothy);
print(smoothy);

var list = smoothy.map(function(num){
```

return ee.Image(ee.Number(num)).rename('NDVI_savitzky_window9_deg3');
    });

```
var col2 = ee.ImageCollection(list);

modis_res = ee.ImageCollection(modis_res);
var col2 = ee.ImageCollection(list);
var modis_res_added_smoothed = modis_res.combine(col2);

print(modis_res);
print(col2);
print(modis_res_added_smoothed);
```

The `modis`in `modis.filterDate(start_date, end_date).filterBounds(aoi);` on line 23 is `the MOD13Q1.006` collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is one way of doing it. First, you need to convert each element in your list to an image, mapping a function. Then,  use combine.

```
var col = ee.ImageCollection([ee.Image(0).rename('uno'), ee.Image(1).rename('dos')])

var list = ee.List([2,3]).map(function(num){
  return ee.Image(ee.Number(num))
})

var col2 = ee.ImageCollection(list)

var combine = col.combine(col2)
print(combine)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot jfoguet. But why it does not work on my code?
I added my code to the question and can be found here:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/02a4f1d070b22669e6fa3f6276eb31a0

Comment: Hello @OverFlow Police, no problem. You need to set a property in common to make the combination. I found a way that works. I'm not sure if it's the most suitable way but it works...[link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/89355cdeb53a7a26193ac1f6d97d6e88)

Comment: yeah. it seems it is like `merge` in R, that uses a column to combine the two. It seems it uses `system:index` to combine them. In your example, when I changed the system index for one of the imageCollections. it did not work. I have to find a way to make my real problem to work now! I wish there was another argument for the `.combine()` function to specify how to combine. Maybe there is. I have not found the documentation of combine on google earth engine yet!!!

Thank you. Let me look @ your new solution. :)

Comment: Do you  know the answer to this one? this should have been my question in the first place.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/362165/get-extract-value-of-a-band-in-an-image?noredirect=1#comment592540_362165

The code for it is https://code.earthengine.google.com/?https://code.earthengine.google.com/1d26adfb351c75380e98a9eace9ffaee