# Get/extract value of a band in an image

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have an `ImageCollection` where each `image` in it has only 1 band called `sum`.
I would like to extract the value of the band and get a list of numbers. How can I do that?
If the `image` is called `im` then `im.get('sum')` would not work.

Link to code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/bff236f76a14eba924d0ed8fcf670619

Comment: Do you just want a vector of numbers that comprise the raster called `sum`? Or do you want the image itself?

Comment: I want an `ee.List` or vector if you will, that is like `L = [sum_1, sum_2, sum_3, ...]` where `sum_i` is the only band value in the `image_i` in the `ImageCollection`. You can assume I have only one `image` with only one band called `sum`. How can I get the value of `sum` in the `image`? Then I can use `map` for all images in the `ImageCollection`

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you want to use image.reduceRegion() https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_reduce_region

Comment: Each of these images correspond to a pixel, it is already just one value. It is not a region. So, reduceRegion does not work (It seems). I had tried that one to trick it (currently, line 79):
https://code.earthengine.google.com/1d26adfb351c75380e98a9eace9ffaee

Answer (score 2):

To get a list of pixel values from an image, you `reduceRegion()` with an `ee.Reducer.toList()` reducer:

```
var region = ee.Geometry.Point([0, 0]).buffer(90).bounds()
var image = ee.Image.random().rename('sum')

var values = ee.List(image
  .reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(), 
    geometry: region, 
    scale: 30
  })
  .get('sum')
)

print(values)
Map.addLayer(image.clip(region).reproject('EPSG:4326', null, 30))
Map.centerObject(region)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/2dc8162bc6ec2d4591dfce31fdd09a36

Comment: is there any good resource for learning about EE and JS? Other than basics that are on Developers page of Google...

Comment: well, your solution does not work on my example: here is the code

https://code.earthengine.google.com/2508dd54ab0bf6c5e870d2d17a654cbb

Comment: You haven't describe in what way the solution fails. You haven't shared your assets, so I cannot run your script. Since your script is almost 400 LOC, I'm definitely not able to see what is wrong by looking at it.

Comment: Here is the asset. https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/hnoorazar/shapeFiles_for_kirti_plots/Grant2017_samples_4_Kirti_plot

I think any shapefile that includes an area would work.

I cleaned up some code and made it 200 lines. Just in case the old link to the code is not updated here it is again:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/bff236f76a14eba924d0ed8fcf670619